# Notice and warning with Video Sidebar Widgets plugin

Tags: wordpress, video, plugins

I'm getting a notice and a warning when I try to delete a post or update something:

> Notice: Undefined index: vsw_noncename in /mysite/wp-content/plugins/video-sidebar-widgets/class-postmetavideowidget.php on line 296
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mysite/wp-content/plugins/video-sidebar-widgets/class-postmetavideowidget.php:296) in /mysite/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881

¿Any hints about this? I have tried to fix the Header Information issue by removing spaces in the file as the codex says but without results, so, probably is another thing.

I'm using wordpress 3.4.2, the plugin version is 5.3 (latest) and a custom theme (checked with Theme-Check and no issues found)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is this when you are using the Wordpress editor or when you try to delete or quick edit from the list of posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin has a bug - it is not checking to make sure that the nonce field exists in the $_POST. Many types of actions that call `save_post` will not have this field, as it is only added on the post editor (line 154 of the plugin).

You should check to make sure that the nonce field exists before validating it. If it does not exist, just return from the function.

To correct it change line 296-297 to read:

```
if ( !isset($_POST['vsw_noncename']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['vsw_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    return;
```

Comment: Thank you doublesharp! I have tried with isset but forgot the ||